# Why are some Detached DOM have unknown distance with native HTML Elements as retainer Objects?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I noticed some Detached DOM have unknown distance and the retainers had something like `native in HTMLAnchorElement` and these retainers aren't live and doesn't have show any javascript references. Why does distance appear to nil `-` for these detached DOMs. Detached DOM also shows `[3404] in (Global handles) @29` , `[13] in (GC roots) @3` in retainer tree. What are the possible ways I could get rid of this Detached DOM. I hereby attach the Screenshot of the Detached DOM obtained from heapsnapshot of Chrome of macOS.
[Screenshot of Detached DOM of unknown Distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFD8v.png) and 
[Screenshot of Retainers showing Global handles and GC roots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIJPa.png)

Comment: Do these nodes disappear after you click the trashcan icon in the toolbar (and do another memory snapshot)? If so, there's no need to worry because garbage collector will remove them eventually.

Comment: No, these nodes do appear even after I click the trashcan icon in the toolbar @wOxxOm

Comment: @wOxxOm: Detached DOM also shows `[3404] in (Global handles) @29` , `[13] in (GC roots) @3` in retainer tree. [Screenshot of retainers showing Global handles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIJPa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but I just wasted quite a bit of time trying to figure this out as well. So hopefully this helps other people facing a similar issue.

Simply run **clear() inside the console in debug tools**, and take another snapshot. (also make sure you dont have any breakpoints set)

Why would this work? I'll let Google explain:

> Sometimes objects may be retained by debugger context and DevTools
>   console (e.g. after console evaluation). Create heap snapshots with
>   clear console and no active breakpoints in the debugger.

(From: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/memory-101)